# How to get value from other variable

Tags: javascript

How to get value from other variable in JavaScript?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--

    var lat0 = 10.212; 
    var lat1 = 11.9090; 
    var lat2 = 12.12;

    var lon0 = 10.212; 
    var lon1 = 11.9090; 
    var lon2 = 12.12;

    var lat = new Array("lat"+i); 
    var lon = new Array("lon"+i);

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {   
        lat[i] = "lat"+i;   
        lon[i] = "lon"+i;       
        document.write(lat[i]);     
        document.write(" ");    
        document.write(lon[i]);     
        document.write(" "); 
    }
    //--> 
</script>
```

I want to get lat0, lat1, lat2, lon0, lon1, lon2 values.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I'd suggest that you'd use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) but you should *really* just use the right data structure from the beginning:

```
var positions = [
    {lat: 10.212, lon: 10.212},
    {lat: 11.9090, lon: 11.9090},
    {lat: 12.12, lon: 12.12}
];

var pos;

for (var i=0; i<positions.length; i++) {
    pos = positions[i];
    document.write(pos.lat + ' ' + pos.lng + ' ');
}
```

**N.B.** be ***very*** judicious with `document.write`. It's almost always better to use DOM manipulation instead. See [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)